# git_merge does not respect the default merge driver configuration setting when checking out conflicted binary files

Tags: libgit2

This is reproducible with commit on master 36bfc27a45ac34e8425271c9d3c79ce62564e195.

Consider the following test point, taken from merge/driver.c. I've added the final assertion cl_assert_equal_file, which fails because conflict markers have been inserted into conflicting.txt:

```
static void merge_branch(void)
{
    git_oid their_id;
    git_annotated_commit *their_head;

    cl_git_pass(git_oid_fromstr(&their_id, BRANCH_ID));
    cl_git_pass(git_annotated_commit_lookup(&their_head, repo, &their_id));

    cl_git_pass(git_merge(repo, (const git_annotated_commit **)&their_head,
        1, NULL, NULL));

    git_annotated_commit_free(their_head);
}

void test_merge_driver__honors_builtin_mergedefault_check_no_conflict_markers(void)
{
    const git_index_entry *ancestor, *ours, *theirs;

    cl_repo_set_string(repo, "merge.default", "binary");
    merge_branch();

    cl_git_pass(git_index_conflict_get(&ancestor, &ours, &theirs,
        repo_index, "automergeable.txt"));

    const char *expected = "this file is changed in master and branch\n";
    cl_assert_equal_file(expected, strlen(expected),
        TEST_REPO_PATH "/conflicting.txt");
}
```

Command line git doesn't try to actually resolve the contents of these files because the default merge driver is binary. I can't see how to get libgit2 to also respect this via git_merge_options and git_checkout_options.

Looking through the source code of libgit2, it looks like either git_merge_file_from_index should be checking config settings and attributes (too low level?) or checkout_create_conflicts should be using the git_merge_driver.

Is this a bug and/or something I can work around?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Your example is also incorrect, as the merge isn't taking place anywhere I can see, and you are merely changing the "merge.default" settings before "iterating for conflicts", not before the merge took place. "merge.default" is a config key, not an attribute, and I have seen no mention of the contents of your .gitattributes, as well.

Comment: I've updated the question to remove mention of .gitattributes, although that also doesn't get respected.

Comment: The merge takes place in merge_branch(), which calls git_merge. This is taken directly from the libgit2 test suite in merge/driver.c, maybe I've misunderstood...

Comment: Okay, so that code does has the following prerequisites : the `.gitattributes` file is created via "set_gitattributes_to()", to enable a "custom" merge filter — and works as expected, because there's a driver by that name. What you're trying to do, force a binary merge, should be possible by passing "binary" to the [git_merge_options.default_driver](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_merge_options) you pass to `git_merge`. This should cause the internal binary driver to be called, instead of auto-selecting from `.gitattributes`.

Comment: I stepped through the git_merge function in a debugger, and it seems all fine (correct merge driver used and the binary files marked as conflicted), until the call to git_checkout_tree, which checks out files marked as binary and writes conflict markers into them.

Comment: I also tried the Github Desktop application (I assume it uses libgit2, could be wrong) and that doesn't respect the merge default in the config, although it does respect the gitattributes.

Comment: I'll try to find some time to look into this properly and open an issue on the libgit2 github page.